# Bumblebee installation on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 and bumblebee on my Lenovo w530 which comes with NVIDIA Optimus card by following this wiki: [Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee)

I am trying to use the DVI ports (2 ports) on my docking station to extend the display. It does not work and I can not even get any output on my VGA.

Answer (score 0):

probably your VGA Port is wired to the nvidia chip

https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Multi-monitor-setup

Greetings isten